# Problem using Synchronize

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety

I need to execute a function in a separated thread and wait until the thread is finished.

For example, here's the original function :

```
Procedure Search;
begin
  CallA;
  CallB;
end;
```

This is the modified function :

```
Procedure Search;
var
  testMyThread: TMyThread;
  Done: Boolean;
begin
  // create a new thread to execute CallA
  testMyThread:=TMyThread.Create(False,Done);
  WaitForSingleObject(testMyThread.Handle, INFINITE );
  if not Done then
  begin
    TerminateThread(testMyThread.Handle, 0);
  end
  else;  
  CallB;
end

unit uMyThread;

interface

uses classes;

type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FDone: ^boolean;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const aSuspended: boolean; var Done: boolean);
    procedure CallA;
  end;

implementation

uses uMain;

constructor TMyThread.Create(const aSuspended: boolean;
  var Done: boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(aSuspended);
  FDone := @Done;
end;

procedure TMyThread.CallA;
begin
  // enumurating several things + updating the GUI
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  Synchronize(CallA); // << the problem
  FDone^ := true;
end;
end.
```

Could you tell me why the thread code above doesn't work (`CallA` never being executed) if I use `Synchronize` inside `TMyThread.Execute` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Synchronize will call a method within application's message loop. And using WaitForSingleObject you simply put all application on hold. Try this:

```
  Procedure Search;
  var
    testMyThread: TMyThread;
    Done: Boolean;
  begin
    // create a new thread to execute CallA
    testMyThread:=TMyThread.Create(False,Done);

    while (not Done) and (not Application.Terminated) do
      Application.ProcessMessages;

    if not Application.Terminated then
      CallB;
  end
```

Comment: This is indeed a solution, but really the form should be adjusted to not block waiting for the thread. After all, the end effect right now is that nothing has changed, only complication has been added. The thread should be started, and then IT should do the work, and then at the end the UI updated. It should not all be in the one Search procedure.

Answer (score 1):

the Delphi tthread class has an event called onThreadTerminate.
This is called in the context of the application thread, when the thread leaves the execute method.

you can use this event in your application.